# how to undo an initial git fetch from HEAD?

Tags: git

Learning to use git and just did an initial 'git fetch' from a repository.

Now that I am done playing with it and am trying to remove the original fetched files, and start all over again with a clean slate (I have messed up the file diretoreis)...how do I do this?

Comment: Git fetch doesn't alter your local branches or working copy - what did you do to "mess up"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git fetch` wouldn't have messed up your directories since it simply downloads content from the remote repository e.g. GitHub.

With `fetch`, the branches that are updated are not your local working branches, but rather branches that are referenced with a *remote* (like `origin`) such as `origin/master` or `origin/featureA`.

But, during your playing perhaps you made changes that you would like to undo.

So, let's first make sure we are on `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

Then, let's undo any potential outstanding changes (you can get these back if needed):

```
git stash -u
```

Fetch again to make sure we have the latest from the server:

```
git fetch
```

Finally, get your `HEAD` pointer (basically points to the commit that your working directory is currently on) back in-sync with the remote:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

As long as you haven't used the `push` command, you are all set and have a clean slate.

Comment: Everything is good and the git fetch was 100% done. "Resolving deltas: 100% (918/918), done." but the git reset command created a failure: "fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
" I am guessing the origin/master is not clear enough for git?

Comment: Also, if I wanted to create a branch locally, say, "test", how do I create a subdirectory to keep track of this branch, after using "git branch test"? I think the command only creates the pointer, but not the actual file directory in the file system?

Comment: @NSCoder The question about "ambigious argument origin/master" is strange because if your origin remote wasn't set up correctly I would expect an error during the git fetch. Perhaps the repo you are pulling from removed it's master branch? As for your second question, that's not really how Git works...branches are simply pointers, it doesn't really make sense to have a separate sub-directory to keep track of a branch. You create any subdirs or files yourself.

Comment: Got it about the second question. The first one is quite interesting. I will dig a bit more.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to reset your use of `git` in this directory. Note that the next step is **completely destructive to your git history**, so do NOT do this lightly.

Now, if you really want to do so, remove all files in your local git tracking:

```
rm -rf .git/
```

You could then reinitialize:

```
git init
```

Comment: The original question stated that he was fetching from a remote repository, so I don't think this is good advice as he would need to re-define his origin and rebase. Probably better to simply remove outstanding changes and reset --hard to origin/master to get a "clean slate"